# Can't use spread operator with ternary operator

Tags: node.js, arrays, typescript, conditional-operator, destructuring

I'm trying to run a command with `spawn` from `cross-spawn` package, to install some dependencies with npm programmatically, these dependencies can be both rollup packages, or webpack packages, depending on the value of the variable `bundler`

```
spawn.sync(
  'npm',
  [
    'add',
    '-D',
    'svelte',
    bundler === 'rollup' ? ...rollupPackages : ...webpackPackages
  ],
  { cwd: projectPath }
)
```

But typescript compiler is complaining, more specifically on the spread operator of `rollupPackages` with the following message:

> `Expression expected. ts(1109)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution, instead of destructuring each variable of the ternary operation, wrapping the entire conditional and destructuring it from the outside worked well, example below:

```js
spawn.sync(
  'npm',
  [
    'add',
    '-D',
    'svelte',
    ...(bundler === 'rollup' ? rollupPackages : webpackPackages)
  ],
  { cwd: projectPath }
)
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same, but I wanted to spread a variable which could be `string | string[]`, so I used `...(typeof var === 'string' ? [var] : var)`. Thanks for the solution, @henriquehbr! :+1: … Actually, the brackets are not necessary → `...typeof var === 'string' ? [var] : var`.

Comment: DIdn't knew that we also could drop the brackets here, thanks for the tip! @tukusejssirs

Comment: Neither did I, but Eslint with [`no-extra-parens`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-parens) rule ([`@typescript-eslint/no-extra-parens`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-extra-parens.md) in TypeScript) warned me about them. From my point of view, it is only logical, as we spread a single thing (a ternary operator). Of course, it is not always true (like when we await a function). And some might see it more understandable with the brackets.

Comment: it doesn't work in this situation
 `headers: ...(data.getHeaders ?data.getHeaders() : { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' })`

Comment: @coder_newbie most probably because you're trying to destructure it inside an object, the example from the answer above does it inside an array

Comment: yup you were right.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both package variables are arrays and you want to add the individual array values as own values in the `.sync` call param array, so try wrapping the entire expression in parentheses:

```
spawn.sync(
  'npm',
  [
    'add',
    '-D',
    'svelte',
    (bundler === 'rollup' ? ...rollupPackages : ...webpackPackages)
  ],
  { cwd: projectPath }
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked, there's also another error pointed by the compiler, it's on the colon of the ternary operator, `',' expected.ts(1005)`